# I need the quickest, easiest way to plot data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot

I'm hacking up a proof-of-concept for a lightweight, generic machine learning algorithm running in Javascript to be used in web apps.

I need a way of quickly visualising large amounts of data by say, plotting 50,000 floats as a function of their index in an array.

Is there anything that can generate such a graph straight from the array of data? Somebody pointed me to visualize.js but I don't really want to screw around with generating markup during the learning process, Javascript is slow enough as it is.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: JavaScript isn't isn't slow, if you're having performance issues it's likely your algorithm.

Comment: I was talking in relative terms. Compared to a dedicated mathematics language that you'd generally use for something like this (I.E Matlab or Octave), yes, it is slow.

Comment: @meagar I see what he's saying. It's "inefficient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jqPlot: http://www.jqplot.com

It has more options than you can imagine for customizing it and it'll display every kind of graph you could ever want. The documentation is a bit convoluted, but other then that it'ss a pretty fast setup.

Direct download link (Aug. 13th 2012): https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads/jquery.jqplot.1.0.3r1117.tar.gz